How to export all vuetify3 components in a customized library?
I am building a reusable UI Component library with Vuetify, Vue 3 and Vite following this guide: https://medium.com/@mattlcoleman88/crafting-a-reusable-ui-component-library-with-vuetify-vue-3-and-gitlab-f7364b0d4b79
Currently I can import the MyButton from the demo app, My question is, if I want to use VBtn from vuetify itself, how can I do it?
Can I export all the vuetify components in my Component library? If yes, how can I achieve it, via vite config or via manual code?
BTW, I know there is another solution is to separate vuetify and the customized library, and add 'vuetify' as a peer dependency in customized library.

You may not need this because this is far more common and reasonable approach, "add 'vuetify' as a peer dependency in customized library"

Thanks for the suggestion, @EstusFlask! I really appreciate it.  We have a lot of similar projects across different teams, and maintaining a consistent UI across them is important.  Having a single source of truth for our Vuetify components would help achieve that goal. Please suggest me if there is another way to achieve UI consistency.

Adding a specific range of vuetify versions to peerdeps would serve that goal IMO. You can't protect other devs from using a footgun. The worst scenario when you reexport vuetify is that a project has another vuetify copy that wasn't deduped and this causes bugs

In the main file of your library, where you export all your custom components, you should be able to add export * from 'vuetify/components' to also export all Vuetify components.
Every export is documented so you can use the same notation to export what you need.

Thanks, @Finrod! Your quick response helped a lot. While exporting all components works, is there a way to include Vuetify contents  (e.g. directives) in the export as well?

Sure! I updated my answer with a link to the corresponding to documentation
